# How to use my project on another computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm so sorry but my English isn't good enough!!

I write a c++ console application program in visual studio 2012 and now i want to run this on another computer without source file and just with exe file
I try to copy .exe file in another computer (windows 7) and run it on that computer but it didn't work!!
what should i do to run this program in another computer ?
can i make a setup file for my console application ?

Thanks....

Here is some of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Person.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream iFile("phonebook.txt", ios::in);
    ofstream oFile("phonebook.txt", ios::out);
    vector<Person *> phoneBook;
    string n, f, t, m;              //baraye inke 0 avale shomare ha ham hesab shavad adadhaye voroodi ra ham az jense string tarif mikonim
    int i,choose,choose2;
    bool flag=true;

    while(flag)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"1. Insert Contact\n2. Show Contacts\n3. Exit\n";
        cin>>choose;
        switch(choose)
        {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            cout << "\t\t\t***Insert New Contact***\n";
            cout<<"\n\nName: ";
            cin >> n ;
            cout<<"\nFamily: ";
            cin>> f ;
            cout<<"\nHome Number: ";
            cin>> t ;
            cout<<"\nMobile Number: ";
            cin>> m;
            phoneBook.push_back(new Person(n, f, t, m));
            for (i = 0; i < phoneBook.size(); i++)
            {
                oFile << phoneBook[i]->getName() << ' ' << phoneBook[i]->getFamily() << ' ' << phoneBook[i]->getTell() << ' ' << phoneBook[i]->getMobile() << endl;
            }
            break;
//....
```

Comment: Build release and install VCRedist for Visual Studio 2012 on target machine. Also, probably a few questions this duplicates as well.

Comment: You might want to clarify how "it didn't work" - did it fail to start (linkage issues), did it crash (if so, when), did it hang...

Comment: *it didn't work* is not a useful problem description. In what **specific way** did it *not work*? Expecting us to create a new project, copy and paste your source code, build it, copy it to a new computer, and run it to find out how *it didn't work* is pretty impolite. You know what you mean by *it didn't work* - tell us if you want us to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Did you consider installing Linux? At least if linking statically the standard C++ library, you might be more happy in uploading your Linux ELF executable to some other Linux system (in particular for similar Linux distributions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target machine will require the VC++ redistributables, or require the executable be packaged with VC++ dependency libraries that can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx).